# Setting up a multi-node Cassandra Cluster distributed across two Linux VMs

Tags: linux, cassandra, redhat

So I have followed the datastax tutorial all of today
But am still unable to get my cassandra cluster up and running.

This is how my yaml file looks for both my cassandra instances:

> Cluster Name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
>
> num_tokens:256
>
> listen_address: 9.98.171.184/9.98.171.183
>
> rpc_address: 9.98.171.184/9.98.171.183
>
> class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
>
> parameters:
>
> > > -seeds:"9.98.171.184"

[This is the error message I am getting for the seed node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oALd2.png)

[However, when I run nodetool status it runs but only for a single node. In addition, the ip address does not look right for what I set to the listen_address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoc1p.png)

I am extremely confused and I would really appreciate any guidance/help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put

```
listen_address: 9.98.171.183
rpc_address: 9.98.171.183
```

on one node and

```
listen_address: 9.98.171.184
rpc_address: 9.98.171.184
```

on another, not two IPs on both.

Also giving public IP to Cassandra is very bad idea in general - by default there's no authorization, anyone from public Internet can mess with your data.

Comment: cool! Thank you. I'm trying to add another node to the cluster now, would it just be the same process? Or do I need to run any nodetool commands on the existing cluster before adding the new node?

Comment: I changed listen and rpc address to be that of the new node's ip and I changed the seed variable to the node I assigned to be the seed of my cluster, but still not working :/ I think it might have to do with the num_tokens or initial_token (I got the value off of the script they provide you on datastax)?

Comment: Strange, it should work. Set IPs for the new node and set seed_ip to `9.98.171.184`. No need to touch tokens anymore and 256 tokens are sane default too. Just make sure that all nodes have same cluster name (same value for `cluster_name` parameter)

Comment: So would 9.98.171.184 be considered a seed as well? So if I add nodes will they newly added nodes just all be seeds? Thanks a ton for the help again!

Comment: Seeds are needed only for cluster bootstrap. If your cluster is small and you creating it manually you can use single node as seed.